# Trying to change UIButton title color and frame on scrollview scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am trying to change the title color of a `UIButton` as well as the frame of the button when I scroll a scrollview to the last page. The `UIButton` is outside of the scrollview.

If I only change the frame it works, and if I only change the title color it works, but when I try to change both the frame doesn't change.

The button I am trying to change is signupButton

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNum = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)

    if(pageNum == 2) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.nextButton.layer.opacity = 0.0
            self.signupButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 159/255, blue: 186/255, alpha: 1.0)
            self.signupButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 69,height: 45)
            self.signupButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        }

    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.nextButton.layer.opacity = 1.0
            self.signupButton.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.signupButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 159/255, blue: 186/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.pageControl.currentPage = pageNum
    }
}
```

I expected both the title color and the frame to change, however only the color changes when I do both. It appears that the `UIButton.setTitleColor()` interferes with the changing of the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the `UIButton's` `titleColor` using `setTitleColor(_:for:)` method, change the `color` using button's `titleLabel`, i.e.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.nextButton.layer.opacity = 0.0
    self.signupButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 159/255, blue: 186/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.signupButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 69,height: 45)
    self.signupButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
}
```